# Mesh Smooth / Remesh on Command Line Interface

Tags: python, mesh, command-line

I'm new to Blender, so my question could be ambiguous.

I need to mesh smooth / remesh / mesh clean up on command line interface.
I read command line part of Blender manual but it seems there's no option about mesh.
I found similar question via google but I want to ask these just to be sure.

Q1. In this case, do I have to write python script for this purpose?

Q2. If so, can I use that script on MacOS and Windows CLI both?

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: A1. You can do it from Blender Python Console, from the script or from the add-on. I'd recommend to watch some Blender Python tutorials, [like this one](https://youtu.be/XqX5wh4YeRw), to have an idea where to start - it will save a bunch of time. A2. in the most cases (except setting absolute paths to files and directories) OS doesn't matter.

Comment: Many appreciate for detailed answer. I gonna try that way.